# In need of JavaFX help writing to a .txt file

Tags: java, javafx

I need to create a JavaFX project that creates a gui to input a name and password. I have created the panes, and set the stage. The items show correctly, however I cant upon button click get the info to write to the file. It creates the file but will not store the data. I need to be able to several names and passwords so I can create a reader login program to check the .txt file. Here is the code I have. 
Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;

public class AddUser extends Application {
    private TextField tfUsername = new TextField();
    private TextField tfPassword = new TextField();
    private Button btAddUser = new Button("Add User");
    private Button btClear = new Button("Clear");

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create UI
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Username:"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(tfUsername, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Password:"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tfPassword, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(btAddUser, 1, 3);
        gridPane.add(btClear, 1, 3);

        // Set properties for UI
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tfUsername.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfPassword.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

        GridPane.setHalignment(btAddUser, HPos.LEFT);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btClear, HPos.RIGHT);

        // Process events
        btAddUser.setOnAction(e -> writeNewUser());

        btClear.setOnAction(e -> {
            tfUsername.clear();
            tfPassword.clear();
        });   

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 300, 150);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Add User"); // Set title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    public void writeNewUser() {      
        PrintWriter fw = null;

        try {
            fw = new PrintWriter("users.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
     * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should close `fw` inside the try block as well as the catch-block.

Comment: @dckuehn Ok I tried that and when I open the .txt file I still don't see the info entered.

Comment: sorry, I commented because it wasn't an answer. It's just something extra I noticed.  You should always close your files/filewriters, and in your code, your file isn't closed unless an exception occurs.

Comment: You've modified the code from the original answer, which technically, work, making the provided answer invalid.  If you're going to change the code, add the updates as a separate block so people can see the progression

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've never heard this before, and I disagree.  I think an edit:update comment would be appropriate, but I don't want to have to scroll through multiple variations of code to try and find the difference.

Comment: @dckuehn Possibly, but the problem now is, at least one of the answers invalid and could attract down votes simply because the original code on which the question was based is no longer valid.  Additionally, the post code should now "work", while not the best solution, it's removed the problem that the question was originally posted for...

Comment: Did you want to use a FileWriter to append text possibly (judging from the var name fw)?  `try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt", true))))`  Where true means append.  Buffered is probably useless here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're "original" had the `fw.close` method within the `catch` block of the `try-catch` in your `writeNewUser` method...

```
public void writeNewUser() {      
    PrintWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new PrintWriter("users.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

As has been pointed out, this will only be called if something goes wrong.  Also, `PrintWriter#close` will throw an `IOException` and `fw` could be `null`, causing more issues...

The modified code is only marginally better...

```
public void writeNewUser() {      
    PrintWriter fw = null;
    try {
        //....
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Placing the `close` call in within the `try` section means that it will only be called if all goes well.  If an exception occurs for some reason, the resource will never be closed

You should also be closing the outer resource, the `BufferedWriter` in this case, this will chain the close call to each enclosing resource.

Instead, you should use a `try-with-resources`, which will close the resources automatically, for example...

```
public void writeNewUser() {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter("users.txt"))) {
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

**Updated**

To append to the file, you might need to use `FileWriter` instead, for example...

```
public void writeNewUser() {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt", true))) {
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
        bw.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: that now works and adds to the file. But I guess I thought with the way I wrote the code, that every time I entered a user I could clear and add more users. It only replaces the existing user. What am I overlooking to make this repeatable?

Comment: So it's overriding the content and you want to update the file?

Comment: Correct, that way if I have 10 people enter info , I can retrieve and check against. I thought with it being a PrintWriter it would do that.

Comment: Generally, file writers overwrite the files unless specified otherwise.  Having looked at the `PrintWriter` I can't seem to see away to do this.  You might consider using `append` instead of `write` or use a `FileWriter` instead, see updates

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within the writeNewUser method:

```
public void writeNewUser() {

    PrintWriter fw = null;

    try {
        fw = new PrintWriter("users.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fw.close();    
    }
}
```

The fw.close() is in the catch loop, but the problem is that it only closes when there is an error (thats why there is a catch block)

The fix for this:

```
public void writeNewUser() {

    PrintWriter fw = null;

    try {
        fw = new PrintWriter("users.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();   
        fw.close 
    }
}
```

^^put the fw.close() in the try and catch block.

As for making it repeatable, try saving the passwords and usernames (Using the scanner class) into an array before initializing the FileWriter, and then have a `for` loop to rewrite the array into the file.

Hope this helps:
Classic

Comment: And if an exception occurs the resource is never closed...Better to use a `try-with-resources`

Comment: @JClassic even with that change it still doesnt write any data to my file. If I open the user.txt file it is blank?

Comment: @MadProgrammer But you never initialized the fw variable outside the try block, so therefore you don't need to close it when it errors.

Comment: @planker1010 try using 

new PrintWriter(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "Desktop", "users.txt"))

This saves it in your desktop

Comment: @JClassic in lieu of new PrintWriter("user.txt")?

Comment: @JClassic Of course you need to close it, it's been initialised within the `try` block ... so the only time it COULD be close is if everything went well, what happens if the `write` method throws an exception?  `close` will never be called, leaking resources...

Comment: @planker1010 yes, and I wrote a suggestion for repeatables^^.

Comment: @JClassic yes that works, but I dont want to have to add in a scanner and add to an array then have to convert.

Comment: Ah, when you create the file writer variable, add a true value right after the file variable in the initialization

Answer (score 0):

missing `bw.close()` is causing a blank file. it should be added as follows:

```
public void writeNewUser() {

    PrintWriter fw = null;

    try {
        fw = new PrintWriter("users.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(tfUsername.getText());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(tfPassword.getText());
        
        bw.close();  //missing this won't write anything into file
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fw.close();    
    }
}
```